# Is there a way to change pandas rows to columns?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this...

```
    name     attributes
0   Car#9    {'trait_type': 'Color', 'value': 'Red'}
1   Car#9    {'trait_type': 'Make', 'value': 'Ford'}
2   Car#9    {'trait_type': 'Model', 'value': 'Mustang'}
3   Car#9    {'trait_type': 'Type', 'value': 'Coupe'}
```

What I need is something that resembles this...

```
    name     Color  Make    Model   Type
0   Car#9    Red    Ford    Mustang Coupe
```

I am reading hundreds of small json files to create the dataframe. Here is what my json input looks like.
I have tried many different methods to get the data where I need it.  I am guessing it is a groupby, transform, or concat that will brighten my day I just cant find it.

```
{
  "name": "Car#9",
  "attributes": [
    {
      "trait_type": "Color", 
      "value": "Red"
    }, 
    {
      "trait_type": "Make", 
      "value": "Ford"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Model", 
      "value": "Mustang"
    }, 
    {
      "trait_type": "Type", 
      "value": "Coupe"
    }
  ] 
}
```

Comment: Please share your code and what you have done so far.

Comment: Thanks for looking yakutsa but I don't have any code to share because I can't figure out how or even if it is possible.  I'm debating just changing the format of my incoming data before putting it into the dataframe

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply(pd.Series)`+`join` to transform your dictionary into columns, then `pivot` the output:

```
(df[['name']]
 .join(df['attributes'].apply(pd.Series))
 .pivot(index='name', columns='trait_type', values='value')
 .rename_axis(columns=None)
 .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
    name Color  Make    Model   Type
0  Car#9   Red  Ford  Mustang  Coupe
```